# Prevent if, elif, else chain (checking input)

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, if-statement, input

If I declare these functions:

```
def f1(someval):
    print(someval)

def f2(someval, someval2):
    print(someval, someval2)
```

And if I have a dictionary that contains the functions as values:

```
input_dict = {"func1": f1, "func2": f2}
```

And I want to check if input from the user matches a key in the ditionary 'input_dict':

```
shell_input = 'shell~: '
for key,val in input_dict:
    if key == shell_input:
        input_dict[val](params)
```

How could I detect how many function parameters there are per each function being called and pass values to them, is it even possible (without declaring global variables)?

I am trying to avoid using chained if, elif, else logic in my code for example:

```
if shell_input == "func1":
    f1(param)
elif shell_input == "func2":
    f2(param1, param2)
#etc...
```

or is it more efficient to use chained if, elif, else logic in when checking input?

Comment: I am not sure to understand your question, is the problem the number of argument, or their nature, i.e. which to use?

Comment: Which is more efficient to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
input_dict = {"func1": f1, "func2": f2}

target = input_dict.get(shell_input)
if target:
    target(*params)
```

input_dict.get(shell_input) will return None if the shell_input doesn't match any of the input_dict keys.

For the params requirement, I'd suggest refactoring your functions as:

```
def f1(*args):
    print(args)

def f2(*args):
    print(args)
```

By doing so, both functions will have the same signature and target(*params) could be used to pass the arguments (using tuple expansion here).

As a more complete example:

```
input_dict = {'func1': (f1, (param,)), 'func2': (f2, (param, param2))}

values = input_dict.get(shell_input)
if values:
    target_func, params = values  # tuples expansion again
    target_func(*params)
```

Note: Each input_dict item contains a tuple with the function and the params.

Comment: What if there are more than one paremeters of the function? How could I pass multiple arguments to the function call? This technique is a more efificent way of checking if key == shell_input though.

Comment: Would it be efficient to call target() with multiple arguments?

Comment: Yes, it's a very handy feature. And it is there because functions can easily get ugly (too many arguments). Check more here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python-3.

Answer (score 0):

I am not fully certain of what you are trying to accomplish..
If the value do not depend on the user input you could use them as default parameters and call your function.

```
def f1(someval=default_value):
    print(someval)

def f2(someval=default_value_1, someval2=default_value_2):
    print(someval, someval2)

if shell_input == "func1":
    f1()

elif shell_input == "func2":
    f2()
```

If the problem is about the number of args you could use unpacking. the args will be an iterable you could iterate over. It also could be use as a dict.

```
def f1(*args):
    for arg in args:
         do 


def f2(**args):
    args1 = args["my_args"]
    args2 = args["my_other_args"]
# ex:
f2(my_args="blue", my_other_args="grey")
```